# Confused about Fourier's Inversion Theorem with another Proposition

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Consider the space $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$.

The Inversion theorem states :

> If $f$ and $\widehat{f}$ are in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, then $\overline{\mathscr{F}}\widehat{f}(t)=f(t)$ at all points where $f$ is continuous.

There is another proposition that is similar which states :

> If $f$ is continuous **and integrable** and if $\widehat{f}\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, then for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ :
> $$
> \mathscr{F}\widehat{f}(x)=f(-x)
> $$

I am lost in trying to differentiate between these two results. Is the proposition (second statement) saying that the inverse of Fourier is now just $f(-x)$ given that $f$ is **also** integrable? because I have seen examples where this proposition is being used to compute inverse Fourier of some functions.

Comment: These results are in the same book, using one definition of the transform and inverse transform?

Comment: It's not clear what you're confused about; surely we understand that "$f$ is integrable" means $f\in L^1$?

Comment: Hello, my concern was only about the proposition I thought it meant that Inverse Fourier is now equal to reflected version of $f(x)$. I acknowledge this embarrassing as I am a beginner to Fourier analysis. Now thanks to nullUser's answer I have understood the results of these two theorems. @DavidC.Ullrich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation of the first theorem is slightly nonconventional. The $\overline{\mathscr{F}}$ is meant to be the inverse Fourier transform, given by the formula
$$
\overline{\mathscr{F}}g(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{2\pi i x \cdot \xi} g(\xi)\,d\xi.
$$
This is what you get if you "complex conjugate" the formula for the Fourier transform
$$
\mathscr{F} f(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-2\pi i x \cdot \xi} f(x)\,dx.
$$
This is not true complex conjugation because $g$ could be complex valued, but the bar didn't get applied to $g$.

The first theorem thus tells you that $\overline{\mathscr{F}}$ actually inverts the Fourier transform and gives you the function back at points of continuity of the function.

The second theorem is not about applying $\mathscr{F}$ then $\overline{\mathscr{F}}$, but rather about applying $\mathscr{F}$ *twice*. Essentially, applying the Fourier transform twice just reflects the function. And hence applying it four times gets you back to the original function. In other words, under suitable continuity and integrability assumptions: $\mathscr{F}^{-1} = \mathscr{F}^3 = \overline{\mathscr{F}}$.

Thus, to answer your question, NO $\mathscr{F} \hat f(x) = f(-x)$ is NOT saying that if $f$ is integrable then the inverse of the Fourier transform is just $f(-x)$. It is saying that the *square* of the Fourier transform is the reflection map, the map that sends $f(x) $to $f(-x)$.